# Cannot get value in Controller using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I had a Controller as shown below and after adding `@Value("${code.url}") final String url`, I encounter the following error:

> *Could not resolve placeholder 'code.url' in value "${code.url}"
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean*

The problem is clearly related to the problem while reading `code.url` in `application.yml`.

***application.yml:***

```
code:
   url: "https://www.gmail.com/"
```

***controller:***

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class DemoController {

    private final DemoService demoService;
    private final Clock clock;
    private final String url;

    public DemoController(final DemoService demoService, final Clock clock,
                           @Value("${code.url}") final String url) {
        this.demoService = demoService;
        this.clock = clock;
        this.url = url;
    }

    //code omitted
}
```

I also tried to use `@RequiredArgsConstructor` in the controller, but it did not make any sense.
So, how can I fix that problem?

Comment: Is that really your `application.yml`?

Comment: See documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-use-yaml-for-external-properties and format your application.yml accordingly.

Comment: @JoãoDias Yes, `application-local.yml`, but of course I omitted other parts.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Sorry, SO did not displayed my code and there is no problem regarding to indentation in my `application.yml`. But the problem continues. Any idea?

Comment: where is the application.yml located in your project?

Comment: @JensBaitinger The problem is not related to the place of `application.yml`, because everything was working.

Comment: `@value ` annotation is not to be used as a parameter in a method, you use it to declare attributes on the class. Move it out from the method declaration to the class and use it (the class attribute) inside your method

Comment: Why do not you post what you wanted to explain?

Comment: @JorgeCampos the `@Value` annotation also works on constructor parameters.

Comment: @binary youre saying other values are loaded correctly from your application.yml?

Comment: what happens if you write `code.url: http://someUrl`?

Comment: @JensBaitinger Thanks a lot for your valuable helps. I fixed the problem, regards...

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
code:
url: "https://www.gmail.com/"
```

to

```
code:
  url: "https://www.gmail.com/"
```

Also, Make sure the location & availability of the appropriate yml file
eg:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, SO did not displayed my code and there is no problem regarding to indentation in my `application.yml`. But the problem continues. Any idea?

Comment: The problem is not related to the place of `application.yml`, because everything was working.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable helps. I fixed the problem, regards... Voted up ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the yaml correctly:

```
code:
   url: "https://www.gmail.com/"
```

otherwise the `url` is on the highest level and the property would be `url` and not `code.url`

Comment: Sorry, SO did not displayed my code and there is no problem regarding to indentation in my `application.yml`. But the problem continues. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable helps. I fixed the problem, regards...

Comment: and what was the issue/solution?

Comment: I add the same value to the `application.yml` of the **test** folder.

Comment: maybe you want to read about [spring profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles). that will help you reducing that duplication. so you have an `application.properties` in your `src/main/resources` and an `src/test/application-test.yml` containing only those value that needs to be different for you tests.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful info. regards

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class DemoController {

    private final DemoService demoService;
    private final Clock clock;
    @Value("${code.url}")
    private final String url;

    public DemoController(final DemoService demoService, 
                          final Clock clock) {
        this.demoService = demoService;
        this.clock = clock;
     }

    //code omitted
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable helps. I fixed the problem, regards... Voted up ;)

Comment: you are very welcome!